# Need a non-X terminal for the nvidia driver installation

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg

When I try to install the nvidia driver for my video card, I receive an error message.

```
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before            
       installing. For further details, please see the section INSTALLING   
       THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver         
       download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

I wasn't able to find the README on the website but how do I create a terminal that is non-X?  I am on 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.
- login using your id / password
- stop the lightdm by `sudo stop lightdm`
- Now install the nvidia driver. If you are using open source driver you might need to restart once and run the steps again.

Comment: I did this and was able to install the proprietary Nvidia driver.  Ctrl-Alt-F7 reverts to the Unity GUI.  However, you will probably regret installing the proprietary Nvidia driver if you have an Optimus GPU.  Use `bumblebee` instead.

Comment: Yea.. Optimus system aren't supported.. Its written in the driver download page

Comment: You really only need the `Ctrl` part of the key combination to switch *from* a virtual console that has X running on it. To switch *back* to your GUI, or from one text-based virtual console to another, `Alt`+`F7` (or `Fn` for another virtual console `n`) is quite sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I've always just done it from single user mode. When booting, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> while grub is loading (i.e., you can just hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as the computer starts up until you get a GRUB menu). Select "recovery mode." Select "root terminal", and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

- First find out the exact command you need to type on the terminal to
  install the drivers. i.e. Something like `sudo apt-get install
  nvidia-something-something`
- Restart the machine.
- On login screen. Switch to one of the virtual console, say
  ctrl+alt+f1.
- Login with a username who has sudo rights i.e. you should be able to run `sudo apt-get install` command.
- Run the command you noted in the first step on the terminal, you see.
- After installation, you can type `exit` to logout and press `Alt+F7` to go back to the gui login screen.
- Use the ubuntu gui.

Comment: he want to install nvidia proprietary driver. Not open source. The above steps will install nvidia open source driver

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back to X.

Comment: The Ctrl-Alt-F1 produces a terminal that results in the same complaint about X Terminal.  To take the error message literally, I guess the problem is the X Server.

Comment: This won't stop x

Comment: Run `sudo service lightdm stop` after login to stop X. Run `sudo service lightdm start` to start X again.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-F7 takes you back to Unity.